# How to Implement AntiForgeryToken in a download link

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

How can I implement an AntiForgeryToken with a download link :

```
@Html.ActionLink("download spreadsheet", "GetSpreadsheet", new { id = "123" })
```

I tried to create an ajax request but i couldn't download the file , the action in the controller is like :

```
        return this.File(path, "application/zip", nomFic);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Aren't anti forgery tokens used for form submission? Downloading a file is usually a GET request.

Comment: Can I use a POST request to download a file ?

Comment: You can (the endpoint to download a file can be whatever verb you want), but I don't see how downloading a file is a Cross Site Request Forgery attack.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to use an `AntiForgeryToken` into a `GET` method.

`GET` methods should only be used for read-only operations on your server. If you want to do something else than a read-only operation, then, you should use a POST method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSpreadsheet", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "123" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value="Download" />
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult GetSpreadsheet(int id)
{
    ...
}
```